# Generic Controller Not Being Registered

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, .net-core

Generated valid types for all my generic controllers and call the PopulateFeature Method in the options of ConfigureApplicationPartManager but when I try to implement a GenericControllerRouteConvention the controller is not in the list of registered controllers.

```
  var providerTypes = new List<Type>();
            var refAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load);
            foreach (var assembly in refAssemblies)
            {
                var candidates = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where( x => 
                    x.IsClass && 
                    !x.IsAbstract  && 
                    x.BaseType.IsGenericType && 
                    x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DataProvider<,>));

                foreach (var candidate in candidates)
                {
                    providerTypes.Add(candidate);
                }
            }

            services.
                AddMvc(c =>
                    c.Conventions.Add(
                        new GenericControllerRouteConvention()
                )).
                ConfigureApplicationPartManager(o => 
                {
                    var contollerFeature = new ControllerFeature();

                    foreach (var providerType in providerTypes)
                    {
                        contollerFeature.Controllers.Add(
                                typeof(DataProviderContoller<,,>)
                                .MakeGenericType(
                                    providerType, 
                                    providerType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0], 
                                    providerType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[1])
                                .GetTypeInfo());
                    }  

                    o.PopulateFeature(contollerFeature);                                       
                });
```

Generic Controller

```
 public class DataProviderContoller<TProvider, TModel, TKey> : Controller
        where TProvider : DataProvider<TModel, TKey> 
    {
        private readonly DataProvider<TModel, TKey> _dataProvider;

        public DataProviderContoller(TProvider dataProvider)
        {
            _dataProvider = dataProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataProvider));
        }        

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Adding the logic directly into the start up class was the cause of my issue. At a different point in the application start up life cycle the populate feature for controller feature will be overridden. I had to create a class that inherited from the I application feature provider:

```
GenericControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
```

The register it in the startup class

```
 services.AddMvc(c =>
                c.Conventions.Add(new GenericControllerRouteConvention()
            ))
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
            {
                apm.FeatureProviders.Add(new GenericControllerFeatureProvider(GetDataProviders()));
            });
```